# Change method based on class of generic

Tags: java, generics, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a simple helper class in java to take in a List of numbers from the user and convert that List into a primitive array for data operations.  I'm stuck on the first step of how to change the scanner input method depending on the List object's class type.  What's the best way to do this?

```
    public static <N> List<N> promptList(String promptString, Class<N> resultType){
    prompt(promptString);
    List<N> inputList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inStream)){
        do{
            inputList.add(scanner.nextDouble());    //switch scanner method based on type of N
        } while (true);
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Input complete");
    }


    return inputList;   
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You would need to check what Type in the list, then see if its `instanceof` what you want.

Comment: Sorry, your question makes no sense to me because `N` can be different number types. For example: `List<Number>`. In fact based in your declaration it can even be `List<String>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if's and the primitive wrapper classes.
Each primitive class has a public static variable TYPE which is a class.
eg: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE

```
if (Double.TYPE = resultType)
 inputList.add(scanner.nextDouble();
else if (Integer.TYPE = resultType)
 inputList.add(scanner.nextDouble();
else if (FLOAT.TYPE = resultType)
 inputList.add(scanner.nextFloat();
```

and more ifs.... for all the primitives you're taking as acceptable input.